# Group by and chose the string value of a column based on a condition using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a **dataframe** consisting of people: ('id','name','occupation').

```
| id |   name   | occupation |
|:--:|:--------:|:----------:|
|  1 |   John   |   artist   |
|  1 |   John   |   painter  |
|  2 |   Mary   | consultant |
|  3 | Benjamin |  architect |
|  3 | Benjamin |   manager  |
|  4 |   Alice  |   intern   |
|  4 |   Alice  |  architect |
```

**Task**:
Some people have multiple occupations, however I need each person to have only one. For this I am trying to use the `groupby` pandas function.

**Issue**: 
So far so good, however I need to apply a condition based on their occupation and here is where I got stuck.

The **condition** is simple: 
if "architect" is in the 'occupation' of the group (person): 
   keep the 'occupation' as "architect" 
else: 
   keep any/last/first (it doesn't matter) 'occupation'

The desired **output** would be:

```
| id |   name   | occupation |
|:--:|:--------:|:----------:|
|  1 |   John   |   artist   |
|  2 |   Mary   | consultant |
|  3 | Benjamin |  architect |
|  4 |   Alice  |  architect |
```

**Attempt**:

```
def one_occupation_per_person(occupation):
    if "architect" in occupation:
        return "architect"
    else:
        return ???
df.groupby(['id','name')['occupation'].apply(lambda x: one_occupation_per_person(x['occupation']),axis=1)
```

I hope this describes the issue clear enough. Any hints and ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `architect` will come out at the first item from a natural sort, you can simply sort on `occupation` and then `groupby`:

```
df.sort_values("occupation").groupby("id", as_index=False).first()
```

If you somehow had another occupation that sorts before `architect`, you can convert the column to `pd.Categorical` before sorting:

```
s = ["architect"] + df.loc[df["occupation"].ne("architect"),"occupation"].unique().tolist()

df["occupation"] = pd.Categorical(df["occupation"], ordered=True, categories=s)

print (df.sort_values("occupation").groupby("id", as_index=False).first())
```

Result:

```
   id      name  occupation
0   1      John      artist
1   2      Mary  consultant
2   3  Benjamin   architect
3   4     Alice   architect
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, the natureal sort would not work in all cases. For example "alchemist" would be before "architect". I am not quite sure what exactly `pd.Categorical` would change in that case. Could you please elaborate?